# SP 2010 Foundation list form with server side validation require redirect after submission

Tags: 2010, list, sharepoint-foundation

- Sharepoint 2010 Foundation (no Infopath!)
- List Form (made a copy of NewItem.aspx and customized it, renamed it) - Save and Cancel buttons are available.
- Also added an additional Submit button (Sharepoint form action) to experiment with what options I have with both buttons.
- Using server side validation on a column.
- some columns are required.

The entire thing works great (all validation).  The only thing I have left is to send the user to a different page when all validation has passed.  Right now, it simply returns the user to the same page to enter in another record.

I've tried various techniques to re-direct (GenFireServer changes, ?Source=) and they all work but what they do is send the user to the thank you page and ignore the server-side validation (it doesn't submit to the list but you don't have an option to fix).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the Sharepoint Form submission button, use the default Save button that is generated when you create a new form.  Then when you give the URL to the end user, ensure you put into the ?source= at the end of the URL.  This worked for us.  I might explore building my own source string in the form so I can send a friendlier URL to the end user.